# Посоветуйте RBAC модуль для Lumen

Tags: laravel, авторизация

Всем привет!
Возникла задача разработать API с ролями для пользователей.
Главное требование: динамическое создание ролей(чтобы админ сам мог создавать роли).
С Lumen и Laravel почти не знаком, поэтому спрашиваю совета у тех кому приходилось решать такую задачу.

Answer (score 0):

[Zizaco/entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) - Не подводил ни разу )

Answer (score 0):

Есть ещё такой пакет чисто для Laravel https://github.com/itstructure/laravel-rbac - работает нормально